# Should I seal my old hardwood floors under my new kitchen cabinets?

Tags: flooring, hardwood-floor, sealing

I'm renovating my kitchen, replacing the old kitchen cabinets which have been there for several decades. When I finished removing the bottom cabinets I found the same softwood floor underneath that is across the kitchen, except that it is not finished. There are remnants of paint but I don't think this section of the floor was ever sealed beyond what might have been done to any flooring in 1930.

Since this is potentially a wet area, does it matter if I leave them as they are, or should I sand them down and add a sealant to protect them before installing the new cabinetry?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is entirely a matter of opinion and your prerogative (budget, will, timeline, etc.). Surface sealant doesn't really protect conventional wood flooring from spills anyway. If there's any substantial water it'll find its way into the joints and underneath and wreak (not wreck) havoc regardless.

Personally I'd probably not bother. There wouldn't seem to be much benefit.

Answer (score 0):

If there isn’t a budget issue and there’s no time restrictions the just go ahead and do it. Everything is out of the way and your entire floor will be starting from the same point in time. Then you know how long the entire floor can last and maybe uncover any other problems beyond what you see from the surface.